# Can I pass an Activity into an Activity and have it execute it?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I want a workflow to execute another workflow.  The latter workflow will be dynamically created and passed in.  Is it possible to have an InArgument that is executed by the Activity that holds it?  I seem to be caught in the problem that I need to tell the CacheMetadata about the InArgument but I can't get it because I don't have a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Windows Workflow Foundation project on CodePlex](http://wf.codeplex.com/) you've a set of useful activities not available out-of-the-box on WF.

In your particular case you want to look at [InvokeWorkflow](http://wf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80373#1255393) which shows you how to pass and execute an Activity inside a workflow.

Furthermore, if you have the activity's XAML you might also want to look at [LoadActivity](http://wf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80373#1255395) and [LoadAndInvokeWorkflow](http://wf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80373#1255396) activities which allows you to pass not the activity object but its XAML instead.